# Github Action fails to execute shell command

Tags: github-actions, workflow

I am trying to run this simple action:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: echoHello
        run: echo "hello"
```

And I get that there was an error, and this message:

```bash
 shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
```

What is the problem here? There is literally anything else in the log.

I also tried with the `Debug` function:

```bash
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/9fc627b8-0668-4ffa-90b3-fb7b1de18b60.sh
```

Any ideas? Could it be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It turns out that you can not pass a repository secret. What is used instead is a "special" secret called `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` that is used to authenticate on Actions.

I wish they had logged an error there. [See the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)